# Logstash Date Has the Wrong Year?

Tags: logstash

I'm parsing Nginx logs into logstash with the following config:

```
input { stdin { type => "nginx"}}

filter {
    grok {
        type => nginx
        pattern => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
    }
    date {
        type => nginx
        match => [
            "timestamp",
            "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z"
        ]
    }
 }

 output { stdout { debug => true debug_format => "ruby"}}
```

Except here's the problem: when I pass in a log with a `@timestamp` of "04/Sep/2012:12:44:16 -0500" I get (as the result timestamp) "2013-09-04T17:44:16.000Z". Wrong year. Is this a bug?

Comment: I just tried your config with an old 2012 apache log and it worked.  This was with the latest logstash-1.2.1.

Comment: I'll add an answer as soon as/if I find one. For now, I just grabbed a different archive log file to sample from.

Comment: Does the different log file work?

Comment: Possibly. It's a log file from 2013 so the problem would be masked.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) as linked to from [logstash documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date#match) you've picked the wrong syntax in your date filter. Try using yyyy (year) instead of YYYY (year of era), I believe that should correct the issue you are reporting.

I hope that helps!